# Unable to execute program from installer

Tags: windows, zip, windows-installer, deployment, nsis

I created an application (exe file) and in order to deploy it I am using two ways:

> 1. **Using zip file**: I zipped the entire contents including executable.
>      This method works and the end user is able to execute the program successfully !
> 2. **Using 3rd party Installer:**
>      I created an installer based on zip file using NSIS but the problem is when the end user tries to execute the executable, splash screen of the executable is being shown for 1-2 seconds and then nothing runs !

I am unable to figure out what's the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am also attaching the zip file and setup for your review.

**Zip File**: [Download Zip File](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxkVT1S-q6d7MGUzLXBBVFdrcTA/edit?usp=sharing)

**Setup** [Download Setup](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxkVT1S-q6d7QUFNNXdEblhlbms/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You can use SystemsInternals ProcessMonitor to monitor your program. Maybe you see some Access Denied logs.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably something to do with privileges. If your NSIS installer is installing into Program Files then the default privileges will not let your app write to the installed folder. Make sure your app is writing to the AppData folder or if you MUST write to the Program Files folder make sure you set the privileges of the sub folders so a standard user can write to them.

To test this out, manually try and run the NSIS installed EXE with admin privileges and see if it now works.

Comment: I tried installing it with administrator privileges too and I also tried installing it to another non windows directory.. but nothing worked !

Comment: If you overwrite the NSIS installed files with the ZIP files (ie the SAME folder) does it start working?

Comment: Surprisingly No.. !

Comment: That definitely looks like a permission thing then. Try, deleting all the files and then copying the ZIP files in, then if that doesn't work re-create the folder. Compare the security permissions of the folder that works with the one that doesn't.

Comment: I compared the security settings of both the folder but all the settings are exactly similar...

Comment: I also copied the contents of the folder copied by NSIS installer in the same directory and surprisingly the executable ran this time !

Comment: Well, there must be some difference. Try using BeyondCompare to see if it can detect the issue.